# How can I change dynamically position of instance of a canvas created in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom, fabricjs

I have make a canvas instance through Fabric.js.

```
var canInstance = new fabric.Canvas("drawCanvas");
```

When I change its position after performing some calculation, it seems no change in canvas position.

```
canInstance.left = "250px";
canInstance.top = "200px";
```

Is there any way to change position of canvas instance dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas object returned by `fabric.getCanvas` does not have `left` and `top` properties.

You need to get the actual DOM canvas and modify its style properties:

```
var canvasNode = canInstance.getElement(); //return the HTMLCanvasElement.
canvasNode.style.position = 'relative';
canvasNode.style.left = '250px';
canvasNode.style.top = '200px';
```

I've changed the `position` property to `relative` because, by default, elements have `position: static`, which causes the layout engine to ignore `top` and `left` properties. If your canvas have a explicit positioning (different to `static`), just remove that line.

Comment: I want to update position of canvas, not it's element.

Comment: What do you mean with *position of canvas, not it's element?* Which position are you referring to?

Comment: Means i want to set left, top position of canvas. I have taken a reference of canvas names as canInstance. Can i change canvas position using instance?

Comment: But which position is that? The position at which you start drawing, or what?

Comment: that is canvas its own position.

Comment: Let's see. You mean the position of the canvas in the page? The position inside the canvas where you're going to start drawing...? Please, specify clearly what you mean, or no one will be able to help you.

Comment: the position of the canvas in the page. can i change it dynamically?

Comment: Yes. **With the code I posted in the answer**. Why did you tell me that you didn't want to update the position of the element? a `canvas`, the true `canvas`, is an element, like everything you see in a web page.

Comment: But after changing my canvas position i can't be able to select my object with in the canvas prpperly. There is problem in selection of object... Is there any other solution of this problem?